# Adding the FAQ on the checkout is a good action?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, e-commerce, checkout

**Adding the FAQ on the bottom of the checkout page is a good action? This could affect my conversion rate positively or negatively?**

I'm thinking to do it because some customers have doubts before proceeding to pay and in some case the delivery price changes (because the user adds different address). But I'm afraid that could be a distraction and generate more doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is best to minimize FAQ as a helper tool to something like checkout. It could be a big distraction to the desired user flow.

If you have specific user pain points, like your shipping example, can you add a tool tip in line with where it is most relevant that shows just that question? The small orange question mark icon in the top right corner of image below is a common pattern that displays a popover of info on mouseover/touch event.

[image: example: the Stack Exchange editor]

That being said, well written FAQs are absolutely a good idea. Some users will be looking for a level of detail that would not work in a tool tip. These articles address best practices for FAQs better than I ever could:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/faqs-deliver-value/
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/faq-ux-deconstructed/